# Ubuntu 22.04: sudo modprobe evdi failed: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Exec format error

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, displaylink

- Are you using the latest driver?
  yes. its 5.6
- Are you using the latest EVDI version?
  yes. 1.11.0
- If you are using a DisplayLink device, have you checked 'troubleshooting'
  on DisplayLink's website?
  yes
- Is this issue related to evdi/kernel?
  yes
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Linux kernel 5.15.0-40-generic

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 and installed the latest release of displaylink driver 5.6. Installation finished okay but the driver is not working. I see the following error.

```
module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 000000001c54c643, val ffffffffc1f44651
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Exec format error
```

Am I missing something? Please advise..

Comment: https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67829

Comment: https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181617-how-to-use-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-with-uefi-sec In a nutshell, disable Secure Boot and try again.

Comment: secure boot is disabled. still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution that worked for me [a here](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/215#issuecomment-889771551). These are the steps to follow.

`sudo displaylink-installer uninstall`

Reboot

`sudo dkms remove evdi/5.2.14 --all -q`

`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

reinstall the displaylink driver and reboot.

Comment: did not work for me